# Jquery fire 2 trigger events asynchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, asynchronous

I have 2 events that need to fire asynchronously because the 2nd event relies on the first event.

Currently I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#CourseID").trigger('change');
    $("#ClearAll").trigger('click');
});
```

Here are the 2 events:

```
    $('#CourseID').change(function() {
alert('Inside CourseID change event');
        Required(document.getElementById('CourseID').value, 'CourseID', 'err_CourseID');
        // Get Hole information & display in Holes
        var CourseID = document.getElementById('CourseID').value;
        document.getElementById('db_CourseID').value = CourseID;
        if(CourseID.length<1) { 
            var holes = document.getElementById('num_holes').value;
            for(i=1; i<=holes; i++) {
                id = "holes_"+i;
                $('#'+id).prop('checked', false);
            }
            document.getElementById('num_holes').value = 0;
            document.getElementById('hole_error').style.display = "inline";
            document.getElementById('holes').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('front9').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('mid9').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('back9').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('ClearAll').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('SelectAll').style.display = "none";
            chkCheckboxes();
            return; 
        } else {
            document.getElementById('hole_error').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('holes').style.display = "inline";
            // Select All Holes
            var holes = document.getElementById('num_holes').value;
            for(i=1; i<=holes; i++) {
                id = "holes_"+i;
                $('#'+id).prop('checked', true);
            }
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: "/P3Live/_includes/php/get_playable_holes.php",
            type: "post",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {CourseID: CourseID},
            success: function(response) {
                if (response.status == "success") {
                    // We need to clear the existing div so when we append it is doing so to an empty field
                    $('#holes').empty();
                    var str = response.message + ''; /* We add the blank space to assure it is recognized as a string */
                    var holes = str.split(",");
                    var sections = holes.length/9;
alert('Setting num_holes');
                    document.getElementById('num_holes').value = holes.length;
                    for(i=0; i<sections; i++) {
                        for(j=0; j<9; j++) {
                            holeNum = (i*9)+j;
                            if(holes.length<holeNum) { continue; }
                            addCheckbox(holes[holeNum]);
                            id='holes_'+holes[holeNum];
                        }
                        var html = $("#holes").html();
                        html = html + "<br />"; // creates a new line after each section of 9 holes
                        $("#holes").html(html);
                    }
                    // We need to have the entire holes div populated before we can check the boxes
                    for(i=0; i<holes.length; i++) {
                        id='holes_'+holes[i];
                        $("#"+id).prop("checked", true);
                    }
                    chkCheckboxes();
                    // Now let's setup which buttons should be visible
                    switch (sections) {
                        case 0:
                            document.getElementById('front9').style.display = "none";
                            document.getElementById('mid9').style.display = "none";
                            document.getElementById('back9').style.display = "none";
                            document.getElementById('ClearAll').style.display = "none";
                            document.getElementById('SelectAll').style.display = "none";
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            document.getElementById('front9').style.display = "inline";
                            document.getElementById('mid9').style.display = "none";
                            document.getElementById('back9').style.display = "none";
                            document.getElementById('ClearAll').style.display = "inline";
                            document.getElementById('SelectAll').style.display = "inline";
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            document.getElementById('front9').style.display = "inline";
                            document.getElementById('mid9').style.display = "none";
                            document.getElementById('back9').style.display = "inline";
                            document.getElementById('ClearAll').style.display = "inline";
                            document.getElementById('SelectAll').style.display = "inline";
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            document.getElementById('front9').style.display = "inline";
                            document.getElementById('mid9').style.display = "inline";
                            document.getElementById('back9').style.display = "inline";
                            document.getElementById('ClearAll').style.display = "inline";
                            document.getElementById('SelectAll').style.display = "inline";
                            break;

                    }       
                } else {
                    alert(response.message);
                }
            },
            error: function(response) {
                for (var k in response){
                    if (typeof response[k] !== 'function') {
                         console.log("Key is " + k + ", value is " + response[k]);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    })
```

This event takes a CourseID from another field and retrieves information from the database regarding the number of holes.  It then creates checkboxes for each hole and checks them by default.   It also sets the display state for some buttons.  One of which, is the secondary event I want to trigger.

```
    $("#ClearAll").click(function() {
        var holes = document.getElementById('num_holes').value;
alert('Inside ClearAll Event.  Holes:'+holes);
        for(i=1; i<=holes; i++) {
            id = "holes_"+i;
            $('#'+id).prop('checked', false);
        }
        chkCheckboxes();
    })
```

As you can see, I inserted alerts to see the order they are firing.  My problem is that the ClearAll event is firing before the hole checkboxes are displayed ('Setting num_holes' alert shows after 'Inside ClearAll Event...').

Any help on getting this to fire asynchronously would be greatly appreciated.  I don't want to use a SetTimeout() as the time could vary based on the user's computer.

Comment: The events don't "fire asynchronously", they fire in sequence, but one of the event handlers has asynchronous code, and you can't really account for that when firing the event, you would probably have to account for that inside the second event handler, or find a better way to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by doing the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#CourseID").trigger('change'); 
    // Now that the course is displayed and set, let's set the default holes
    // First we will clear all holes
    $(document).ajaxStop(function(){
        // This all needs to be done ONLY after CourseID change event is done
        $("#ClearAll").trigger('click');
        var holes = [];
        holes = "<?php echo $row['holes']; ?>";
        holes = holes.split(",");
        for(i=0; i<holes.length; i++) {
            alert(holes[i]);
            id = "#holes_"+holes[i];
            $(id).prop("checked", true);
        }
    });
});
```

Using the .ajaxStop assured the ajax queries were complete.  The rest happens extremely quick so that was not an issue.  By then including my secondary function within the .ajaxStop - everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your change event function into named function and add callback that will fire after ajax:

```
function OnChangeEvent(callback) {
    Required(document.getElementById('CourseID').value, 'CourseID', 'err_CourseID');
    ...
    $.ajax({
        url: "/P3Live/_includes/php/get_playable_holes.php",
        type: "post",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {CourseID: CourseID},
        success: function(response) {
            ...
            if (typeof callback == 'function') {
                callback();
            }
        },
        error: function(response) {
            for (var k in response){
                if (typeof response[k] !== 'function') {
                     console.log("Key is " + k + ", value is " + response[k]);
                }
            }
            if (typeof callback == 'function') {
                callback();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

and you call use this function as:

```
$('#CourseID').change(OnChangeEvent);
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    OnChangeEvent(function() {
        $("#ClearAll").trigger('click');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you move the ClearAll trigger to the end of the ajax success callback within the $("#CourseID").trigger('change') event?

Comment: But this will fire click event on every change of #CourseID it need to happen only on init.

Comment: true. then callback is the way to go